# magento media folder autocreated

Tags: php, magento

How can i stop magento from auto creating the media folder? I have a media folder with all the correct files that I want to use but when I rename the current media folder it automatically gets re-created; Whats causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Once, I was caught in same situation, what worked for me was..

- delete `app/etc/local.xml`
- Upload your `Media` folder
- Re-run the Installation wizard

it worked for me a about a month ago, my version was Mag EE-1.12

hope this helps

Comment: i tried that and it errored and said a install sql file was missing. so i renamed local.xml back and now the site shows as a blank page. whats causing it to show itself as a blank? errors should be turned on.

Comment: http://support.xtento.com/wiki/I_am_getting_a_blank_page_with_one_of_your_extensions do this and see what is the error exactly

Comment: if i do a reinstall will it overwrite existing data? or remove it? There are about 4000 products

Comment: if you delete the local.xml, and run installation wizard, basically, all the config is loaded again, so, you will not loose product data, still, backup up database and Mag is something you should always do